# error inserting instance with gcloud api gem

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-api-ruby-client

trying to launch an instance in Google Cloud using `google-api-client` 0.9.2 
So I'm running:

```
compute.insert_instance(project, zone, instance_opts)
```

Where `instance_opts` is:

```
---
machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/openshift-gce-devel/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
disks:
- initializeParams:
    sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/images/myimage
  type: SCRATCH
networkInterfaces:
- network: projects/myproject/global/networks/default
  accessConfigs:
  - name: external
name: mytest
```

But I'm getting an error from server:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required field 'resource.name' not specified"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required field 'resource.name' not specified"
 }
}
```

I'm getting exact same issue even if I make `instance_opts` only:

```
{"name": "mytest"}
```

I get an error for unknown field "resource" or "resource.name" if I try to set these in `instance_opts`. Setting name of disk also doesn't help. So I'm wondering what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, might be stupid but I couldn't understand it for a good time that I actually have to create an `Instance` object and use it for the call.

```
io = Google::Apis::ComputeV1::Instance.new(instance_opts)
compute.insert_instance(project, zone, io)
```

But with one more detail. Hash should be `:machine_type` instead of `"machineType"`. That's the same for all hash keys.